# Fit plot to space column layout in Quarto revealjs

Tags: css, r, r-sf, quarto, reveal.js

I have a code and a map that I would like to plot on the side, so I use `output-location: column`. The map however, appears very small compared to the code. Is there any way to make it fit the width and height?

I've tried by reducing the margins: `par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))`, but it does not change anything. I've also tried `out-width` and `out-height` with integers (percentages do not work in `revealjs`), but this destroys the aspect ratio.

Any ideas?

````
---
format: revealjs
---

## A title

```{r}
#| output-location: column
#| echo: true
library(spData)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

#par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nz) + 
  theme_minimal()
```
````

[image]

Note: this seems to be a common problem with `sf` objects: [Eliminate Outer Margin (Ggplot2 / geom_sf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67687029/eliminate-outer-margin-ggplot2-geom-sf).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76399214/how-can-i-adjust-code-block-and-output-size-on-specific-slides-of-a-quarto-revea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 01

One option could be saving the map and then using `knitr::plot_crop` to get an image of the map where extra white margins will be cropped off and then render the image with `magick::read_image`.

I have also used a bit CSS to tune the map height a little bit and get a nice output.

````
---
title: "Fit plot to space column layout"
format: revealjs
---

## A title

```{r}
#| output-location: column
#| echo: true
#| classes: map
library(spData)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(magick)

map <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nz) + 
  coord_sf(expand = F) +
  theme_minimal()

ggsave("map.png")
. <- knitr::plot_crop("map.png")
print(
  image_read("map.png"), 
  info = FALSE
)
```

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.reveal .map img {
  height: 80vh;
  padding-left: 2em;
}
```
````

---

[image: map with removed border]

### Option 02

You can use the knitr hooks [`knitr::hook_pdfcrop`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/crop-plot.html) to do all of the steps of option 01 in one go.

At first enable it by setting it in `knit_hooks$set()` and then use `crop: true` in the code chunk.

````
---
title: "Fit plot to space column layout"
format: revealjs
---

## A title

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(crop = knitr::hook_pdfcrop)
```


```{r}
#| output-location: column
#| echo: true
#| crop: true
#| classes: map
library(spData)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)


ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nz) + 
  coord_sf(expand = F) +
  theme_minimal()

```


```{css, echo=FALSE}
.reveal .map img {
  height: 80vh;
  width: auto !important;
  padding-left: 2em;
}
```
````

---

[image: figure for the second option]

Comment: Nice! I'm trying to reproduce this, and one thing that bothers me is the fact that there is no space left at the bottom. (see the second output). Any ways of creating a little space using the second option (but output as in first option)? I tried to add a `padding-bottom` option but without success

Comment: @Maël, I have updated the answer for 2nd option with a bit more of css.

Comment: Ok. By working a bit with vh parameter, I managed to make it work! For some reason, 50 is working for me, but 80vh goes beyond the size of the slide.

Comment: I am giving the bounty to this answer because the CSS class allows for more customization of the output.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use the `fig-asp` option like this:

````
---
format: 
 revealjs
---

## A title

```{r}
#| output-location: column
#| echo: true
#| fig-asp: 1
library(spData)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

#par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nz) + 
  theme_minimal()
```
````

Output:

[image]

Comment: Although this is very straightforward, two things I wonder: whether this is gonna work in unusual output format (high width low height or vice versa), and if we can make the labels bigger

Answer (score 1):

You could use `max-width`, but I hope that there are better ways:

````
---
format: revealjs
---

<style>
.reveal img {
  max-width: 150%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
</style>

## A title

```{r}
#| output-location: column
#| echo: true

library(spData)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nz) + 
  theme_minimal()
```
````

[image]